# Tkinter app disappears when exiting full screen

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, fullscreen

I have a python tkinter application and want to display it in full screen when starting it (in Ubuntu if that matters). So I used `Tk.attributes('-zoomed', True)`. If I pull the window out of full screen with the mouse it just disappears. I can still see the application's icon - so it's still open - but I can only see my empty desktop and clicking on the icon doesn't make it visible either.
When I define the window's size with `Tk.geometry('1500x800')`, then make it full screen and exit full screen again like before it doesn't disappear.
What could be the reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

edit: I'm sorry, I wrote the question from memory and it's been I while since I wrote that and Tk is not my real variable name. Here is the actual code:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        # Set the window's size
        self.geometry('1500x800') # set size manually
        # self.attributes('-zoomed', True) # fullscreen with toolbar
        # self.attributes('-fullscreen', True) # fullscreen
```

...

Comment: Is `Tk` the variable name? You might wanna try by changing that to something else.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to set the fullscreen attribute to True, it is as easy as:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

> However, it doesn't show the title bar. If you want to keep it visible,  **you can resize the Tk element with the geometry() method:**

```
root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that's not really what I wanted to know. I am able to get a full screen application as I found the code in your answer somewhere else as well. I'm just curious and want to understand why my applications disappears with the -zoomed attribute.